# How to Stop Chrome Caching During Visual Studio Blazor Wasm App Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, caching, blazor

I am using a small Blazor Wasm app to learn web programming.  In particular, Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.6.2 with AspNetCore v3.2.0 and Chrome v83.0.4103.116.  There are times when changes I make to my code (JavaScript and Blazor) aren't applied when I run the debugger, unless I do a Hard Refresh.  I have set 'Disable cache' in the Network portion of the Chrome DevTools, but it doesn't remain set between debugging sessions.  Having to do a Hard Refresh each time I debug just in case is of course a big pain.  Any idea what I can do to prevent caching under these circumstances?

Comment: I have the same problem and still looking for an solution :(
Even when I publish I and to force the refresh ....

Comment: I just did a quick test and found that the problem MAY be gone.  I say MAY because I was never sure what situations it happened versus not.  I am now using VS Community 2019 v16.8.2, AspNetCore 5.0, and Chrome v87.0.4280.66.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short answer

At the beginning of your **index.html** file, before any Blazor initialization, write a Javascript method call that clear the Blazor cache:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    caches.delete("blazor-resources-/").then(function (e) {
        console.log("'blazor-resources-/' cache deleted");
    });
</script>
```

By doing this, the **Cache Storage** will be cleared at each page load, just before the Blazor initialization.

### Full answer

I think it is better to control the behavior of this depending the context.
For a basic if in **Debug** or **Release** configuration, assuming that you are hosting your **Blazor WASM** application on **ASP.NET Core**, here are the steps:

- Copy your **index.html** file from your **Client WASM** project on your **Server** project, in a **Pages** folder you may have. In my case, i have copied it in **./Pages/**
- Rename the file to **_Host.cshtml** or something suitable for you.
- Open this new file. We will now state in it that this is the root page if this page come from a routing context, and we will add our **clear cache** logic depending we are actually in **Debug mode** or not. You file content may look like this:

```html
@page "/"
@{
    Layout = ""; //Force no Layout

    bool clearCache = false;

#if DEBUG
    clearCache = true;
#endif
}
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>MyProject</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Beeworking.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    @if (clearCache)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            caches.delete("blazor-resources-/").then(function (e) {
                console.log("'blazor-resources-/' cache deleted");
            });
        </script>
    }
    <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

- Now in your **Startup.cs** file in your **Server** project:
  Change:

  ```
  endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
  ```

  To:

  ```
  endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
  ```
- If it don't work, you may have to specify the root search path for **Razor views**. In **ConfigureServices**, change **AddRazorPages** to something suitable on your current configuration to find your starting view:

  ```
  services.AddRazorPages(options => options.RootDirectory = "/Pages");
  ```
- **That's it !** . If everything goes right, your Blazor WASM index page will now be the CSHTML one at boot, and because we condtionnally inject the clearing cache code, the cache will be cleared at every page load, but the behavior will not be present when the app will be published or built in **Release** configuration mode.

Answer (score 0):

After publishing there is a file at wwwroot/_framework/Blazor.boot.json

Change cacheBootResources to false.

{
"cacheBootResources": **false**
...

Clear your cache on the client browser.