# Blazor WASM - unable to find JavaScript lambda function on the page

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

Following the documentation from Microsoft:

[Download from a stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#download-from-a-stream)

In my `client` project I have the following in the index.html file:

```
...
    <script>
        window.downloadFileFromStream = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
            const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
            const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
            anchorElement.href = url;
            anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
            anchorElement.click();
            anchorElement.remove();
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

And in my razor Page, I have a (MudBlazor) button with the following attribute:

```
OnClick="@(async () => await DownloadAsync())"
```

That function is defined as:

```
private async Task DownloadAsync()
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new();
    using StreamWriter writer = new(ms);
    writer.Write(csvData);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string fileName = $"TheFile_{now:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}.csv";
    using DotNetStreamReference streamRef = new(stream: ms);

    await this.JS.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFileFromStream", fileName, streamRef);
}
```

I publish the code and then execute it, and when that gets executed I get the error message:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find
> 'downloadFileFromStream' ('downloadFileFromStream' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'downloadFileFromStream'
> ('downloadFileFromStream' was undefined).

If I show the page source, I can see the JS function, so why can't my code find it?

### Update 1

When the page first loads with this functionality on, if I first hit [Ctrl+F5] to do a hard reload of the page, then it works fine.  But, opening it in a new browser window has the same error.  I can't have a message to say "hit [Ctrl+F5]" when this page first loads for it to work properly..."

Comment: change the define function and test it: async function downloadFileFromStream(fileName, contentStreamReference) {...

Answer (score 0):

I use this exact function and it works well, the only difference I have is the function is defined in a file then the file is imported.

It is included in the html body like this

```
<script src="blazor-local.js"></script>
```

I will admit that I can't understand why it would make a difference, but I would try it out. There might be something about the definition not being loaded on first pass because it is defined directly in the html.../shrug. Did you post this to the [dotnet/Aspnetcore Github?](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore)

Answer (score 0):

Emptying cache and hard refreshing should fix this.
(in Edge: right click the refresh symbol for this action)

Using a separate js file does not work, neither the js file nor the index.html is updated unless you empty cache.

If you want this to happen automatically you can use this script i found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65903351/14398924 :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    caches.delete("blazor-resources-/").then(function (e) {
        console.log("'blazor-resources-/' cache deleted");
    });
</script>
```

You have to empty the cache one final time for this script to take effect, though.

Comment: I think there is an actual answer in there, but I recommend to [edit] and to reduce the overall impression of this being a "me too" post, which risks being deleted. Try for [answer].

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'm not used to posting on SO. Edited my comment to fit community standards

Comment: Thanks for taking my feedback. I recommend the [tour] to get into things here. E.g. your post is an answer, not a comment. The difference is important on StackOverflow. Have fun and welcome.